# Deploy Django docker image with Jenkins

Tags: django, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, ansible

I would like to deploy the Django Docker image with Jenkins.

I already had this pipeline created with the middle docker registry.
For this, I have 2 Jenkins tasks

1. Build the image and transfer to registry
2. Pull from registry to desirable server and start image

Now, I would like to avoid the docker registry to speed up the deployment.

Right now I have something like this, but it DOESN'T work:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ HOSTS|default('docker') }}"
  remote_user: "{{ USER }}"
  vars:
    deploy_port: "{{ DEPLOY_PORT|default(8080) }}"
    git_branch: "{{ GIT_BRANCH|default('Development') }}"
    python_settings: "{{ PYTHON_SETTINGS|default('Development') }}"
    su_user: "{{ SU_USER|default('test') }}"
    su_email: "{{ SU_EMAIL|default('test@test.si') }}"
    su_password: "{{ SU_PASSWORD|default('test') }}"
    app_container_name: "{{ APP_NAME|default('test') }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Remove old image
    docker_image:
      name: my-project-name-{{ git_branch }}
      state: absent
      force: yes
  - name: build django image
    docker_image:
      path: .
      name: my-project-name-{{ git_branch }}
      nocache: yes
  - name: Start django image
    docker_container:
      name: "{{ app_container_name }}"
      image: my-project-name-{{ git_branch }}
      state: started
      restart: yes
      restart_policy: always
      ports:
      - "{{ deploy_port }}:80"
      env:
        PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 0
        DJANGO_ENV_NAME: "{{ python_settings }}"
        SU_USER: "{{ su_user }}"
        SU_EMAIL: "{{ su_email }}"
        SU_PASSWORD: "{{ su_password }}"
      tty: yes
```

This give me the error in Jenkins

```
raise errors.APIError(e, response, explanation=explanation)\r\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"{\"message\":\"Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile\"}\")\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/var/jenkins_home/workspace/my_project STAGE/run_test.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
stage                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: I don't think the [build] tag helps your question any. It looks like you are using an ansible script though, so your question could benefit from the [ansible] tag.

Comment: Have you verified that your `Dockerfile` is where you expect it to be?

Comment: @ShaneBishop: yes - the build works normally. If I run build from terminal it works normally, or if I deploy with 2 steps deploy.